# Difference between non-clustered row based index and column- store index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

What is difference  between non-cluster row based index and column- store index?
For example , there is a table with these columns:

```
ID, Name, family, Description
```

Index creation scripts:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name   
ON TestTable (Name);   


CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_Name_CS 
ON TestTable (Name);
```

I think in index page two above indexes have same structure? So what is difference between two above indexes?

Comment: The first index is a traditional rowstore b-tree index, optimized for lookups and ordered scans. The second is a columnstore, optimized for scans of rowgroups of 1M rows. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide) does a good job of describing the differences along with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row-store and column-store indexes are quite different.  Have you reviewed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017)?

However, for a single column, the differences for *non-clustered* indexes are smaller.  One fundamental difference is that the column-store automatically compresses the data.  This can significantly reduce the size of the index.

On the other hand, column-store indexes are not generally used for *index seek* operations.  Generally the entire column is scanned.  Because the column in the column store index is much smaller in the row, this is much faster than a full table scan.  It is also generally faster than a scan on the row-store index with one column.

Which index to use depends on the types of queries you want to run.  I suspect that for a single column, the row-store is more appropriate in more situations.